# Disable Pre-processing in GAMS

Tags: mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, gams-math

When solving a non-linear problem (NLP) in [GAMS](http://www.gams.com/), I would like to disable pre-processing of equations, because I believe the procedure may be improperly underestimating my feasible space. Is there an option flag to do so?

Comment: I haven't seen any other questions about GAMS on Stack Overflow. If you don't get a response, you might want to try a forum or group dedicated to GAMS.

Comment: I think this depends on the solver you are using. Are you using CONOPT?